# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException en mi matriz

Tags: java, poo, eclipse, herencia, polimorfismo

Tengo un método para crear enemigos, los enemigos debo crearlos en casillas y las casillas son una matriz de 30 x 40 que forman el tablero, pero en mi método crear enemigos me da este error de NPE, la verdad no sé que lo causa si ya tengo instanciado todo, adjunto una imagen con el error y la ubicación y el código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora adjunto mi código el problema es el método crear enemigos, los enemigos se van creando, por ahora la matriz solo tiene el tamaño está vacía y la idea del método es irla llenando.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Juego {

    private Jugador jugador;
    private Enemigos[][] enemigos;
    private Fondo fondo;
    private TanqueAntidoto tanqueAntidoto;
    private Blaster blaster;
    private Nivel nivel;
    private Tablero tablero;
    private Casilla[][] casilla;
    
    public Juego() {
        this.blaster = new Blaster();
        this.jugador = new Jugador(blaster);
        this.fondo = new Fondo();
        this.tanqueAntidoto = new TanqueAntidoto();
        this.enemigos = new Enemigos[30][40];
        this.tablero = new Tablero();
        this.nivel = new Nivel();
        this.casilla = new Casilla[30][40];
        this.crearEnemigos();
    } // Constructor

    private void crearEnemigos() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.enemigos.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.enemigos.length; j++) {    
                    if(Nivel.aparicionVirus[i][j] == 1) {
                        enemigos[i][j].setEnemigo(new CepaL(enemigos[i][j].getX(),enemigos[i][j].getY()));
                        casilla[i][j].setEnemigo(this.enemigos[i][j].getEnemigo());
                        tablero.setCasilla(casilla);
                    } // If
            } // For j
        } // For i
    } // Crear Enemigos

    public void dibujar(Graphics g) {
        this.fondo.dibujar(g);
        this.jugador.dibujar(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < casilla.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < casilla.length; j++) {
                if(casilla[i][j] != null) {
                    tablero.getCasilla();
                    casilla[i][j].getEnemigo().dibujar(g);
                    
                    
                } // If
            } // For i
        } // For j
    } // Dibujar

    public void actualizar() {
        this.tanqueAntidoto.actualizar();
        this.jugador.actualizar();
        this.jugador.chequearAtaque(this.enemigos);
    } // Actualizar

    // Setter && Getters

    public Jugador getJugador() {
        return jugador;
    }

    public void setJugador(Jugador jugador) {
        this.jugador = jugador;
    }

    public Enemigos[][] getEnemigos() {
        return enemigos;
    }

    public Fondo getFondo() {
        return fondo;
    }

    public TanqueAntidoto getTanqueAntidoto() {
        return tanqueAntidoto;
    }

    public Nivel getNivel() {
        return nivel;
    }

    public void setEnemigos(Enemigos[][] enemigos) {
        this.enemigos = enemigos;
    }

    public void setFondo(Fondo fondo) {
        this.fondo = fondo;
    }

    public void setTanqueAntidoto(TanqueAntidoto tanqueAntidoto) {
        this.tanqueAntidoto = tanqueAntidoto;
    }

    public void setNivel(Nivel nivel) {
        this.nivel = nivel;
    }

} // Class Juego
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando creas el arreglo, no estás creando los 120 enemigos *dentro* del arreglo:

```
this.enemigos = new Enemigos[30][40];
```

En ese punto, las 120 localidades del arreglo tienen `null` en ellas.

Por ende, en algún momento tienes que llenar esas 120 localidades con instancias  de Enemigo (cosa que no veo que esté sucediendo en el código presentado). Si en tu código comienzas a hacer un recorrido llamando a métodos de las instancias que no están aún definidas (como `setEnemigo()`), vas a tener NPEs, como es el caso.

**Cuanto corto**: crea las 120 instancias de Enemigo y las guardas en el arreglo antes de empezar a utilizarlas.

Comment: crear las 120 instancias? eso cómo sería?, disculpame por los errores de novato

Comment: tranquilo... no tienes que pedir dusculpas... podría ser algo como: `for (int i =0; i < 30; i++) {for (int j=0; j < 40; j++){this.enemigos[i][j] = new Enemigo()}}`. La llamada donde estás recibiendo el NPE me parece rara.... pareciera que en ese punto estás _justamente_ definiendo el enemigo... pero, en vez de asignarlo en la localidad del arreglo, estás llamando a un método `setEnemigo` (de la instancia que en este momento es null, como estamos diciendo). O sea que la clase `Enemigo` tiene un método que se llama `setEnemigo()`? Eso suena _raro_, por decir lo menos.

Comment: es que en la clase casilla tengo un atributo privado de tipo enemigo. En las casillas siempre hay o no hay enemigos, las casillas son una matriz de 30 x 40, que conforman el tablero.

Enemigo() me da error ya que no puedo convertir de Enemigos[][] a Enemigos

Comment: en este caso sería así, enemigos[i][j] = new CepaL(enemigos[i][j].getX(),enemigos[i][j].getY()); no?

Comment: Enemigo es una clase abstracta, CepaL, CepaV y CepaS son clases que heredan de enemigos, o sea son enemigos

Comment: Exacto.... _eso_ tiene sentido. Pero entonces en la asignación de la casilla haces: `enemigos[i][j] = new Cepal(blablah);`. yea?

Comment: Es que debo identificar en qué casilla hay enemigos y en qué casillas no, por eso quiero hacer la asignación en al casilla. PD: ya lo cambié como lo hice arriba pero igual me da NPE.

Comment: ok, el NPE me lo da a la hora de los parámetros en donde creo la Cepa, lo he cambiado y esa línea ya no me da NPE, ahora la que me da error es la línea de código de casilla

Comment: Ok... es que ahí estás demostrando que tienes un error conceptual. Como te dije en la respuesta original: Cuando creas el arreglo con el `new Enemigos[30][40]`, no estás instanciando _nada_ **aparte del arreglo**. Las 120 casillas estan vacias, todas tienen `null`. Si tratas de llamar al método `setEnemigo()`, estás haciendo `null.setEnemigo()` y eso va a generar un NPE.

Comment: En este caso entonces cómo logro crear un enemigo en esa casilla, ya cree el enemigo ahora entonces sería colocarlo en la casilla.

Comment: _creo_ que lo que quieres hacer es esto: `enemigos[i][j] = new Cepal(blablah);`

Comment: si, eso ya lo hice, pero también quiero que haya un enemigo en la casilla, ya que lo necesito para otro método.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que pones parece que faltaría crear los objetos de tipo `Enemigo` para cada una de los elementos del array `enemigos`.

Tendrías que crearlos usando el constructor justo encima de la línea donde haces el `setEnemigo`:

```
enemigos[i][j] = new Enemigos();
enemigos[i][j].setEnemigo(new CepaL(enemigos[i][j].getX(),enemigos[i][j].getY()));
```

Comment: yo ya hice esa instancia en el constrcutor de Juego

Comment: creo que dices esto.

enemigos[i][j] = new CepaL(enemigos[i][j].getX(),enemigos[i][j].getY());

Comment: Enemigo es una clase abstracta, CepaL, CepaV y CepaS son clases que heredan de enemigos, o sea son enemigos

Comment: Eso es, realmente no conozco la jerarquía de clases, pero sí quería decir cualquier instancia de tipo `Enemigos`. Por cierto, he visto que con casillas pasaría algo parecido, no veo donde se instancian así que tal vez habría que instanciar cada elemento del array de forma similar

Comment: la única sería esa, las cepas son Enemigos, herendan de la Clase Enemigos y la clase Enemigos es abstracta, listo muchas gracias

Comment: los instancié en Juego arriba, this.enemigos = new Enemigos[30][40];